# Starting browser automatically from script (not from Autostart/Desktop) in Lubuntu 12.04

Tags: chromium, lubuntu

I have a miniPC running Lubuntu 12.04. As of now it logins automatically & I am able to bring up the Chromium browser by adding a chromium-browser.desktop file in .config/Autostart/ folder. However, I would like to start the browser automatically from a script so I can control which URL it starts up depending on the status of the wireless connection. I tried adding the "exec...chromium-browser..." line in my /etc/rc.local but that doesn't seem to start up the browser at reboot. If I run rc.local explicitly from command line, that brings up the browser.

How can I run the browser from a script (not from /root/.config/autostart/chromium-browser.desktop) so it goes to URL 1 if wireless is active and URL 2 (local HTML file) if wireless is not active and brings up the wireless connections window?

Thank you. Any help would be appreciated.